# How to change google support design sliding tab style with custom fonts in android

Tags: android, android-support-library, slidingmenu

I am making android app with sliding tabs by google support design. I want to set custom font in sliding tabs name. Right now i am able to change the style and size of tabs name but not able to change.[image]

here i want to change font of SAMA Stadium and Manjalpur stadium.
I have tried this but i think we cannot change font style from this.
So, How can i change this font style.
My custom font in asset folder is HelveticaLTStd-UltraComp.otf

```html
<style name="TextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab" >
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

my code

```html
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_tabback"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ec3c08"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ec3c08"
            app:tabTextColor="#22b14c"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextStyle"/>

     

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity{

Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private TabAdapter mAdapter;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
DatabaseOperation databaseOperation;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);

    databaseOperation = new DatabaseOperation(Home.this);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    String pos = sharedPreferences.getString("position", "");

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    mAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

    setTitle("");

    if (!(pos.equals(""))) {
        Log.d("pos", pos);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.valueOf(pos) - 1);
    }


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] tabsName = {"Sama stadium", "Manjalpur Stadium"};

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            SamaStadium samaStadium = new SamaStadium();
            return samaStadium;
        } else {
            MakarpuraStadium makarpuraStadium = new MakarpuraStadium();
            return makarpuraStadium;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabsName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabsName[position];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use a custom `TabLayout` extending original `TabLayout`. And then applying a custom Font in its constructor.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Applying Custom Font in whole Application use this link : https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076

**CustomTabLayout.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by HP-HP
 */
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(@NonNull PagerAdapter adapter) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/avenir_next_medium.ttf");

        this.removeAllTabs();

        ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
            Tab tab = this.newTab();
            this.addTab(tab.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
            AppCompatTextView view = (AppCompatTextView) ((ViewGroup)slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(1);
            view.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i apply this to my tabLayout?

Comment: same as you are using normal `TabLayout`. E.g. instead of `private TabLayout mTabLayout;` use `private CustomTabLayout mTabLayout;` and everything remain the same.

Comment: It is generating classcastexception that TabLayout cannot be cast to CustomTabLayout

Comment: obviously dude because you might not have changed this line `mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);` to `mTabLayout = (CustomTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);` and in Xml also change the `TabLayout` to your specified package name.CustomTabLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use Calligraphy for custom font

[calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

In Application class,

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build();
```

Then Custom font per view as

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

and many more please follow the link.

Or use CustomTabLayout as:

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(@NonNull PagerAdapter adapter) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");

    this.removeAllTabs();

    ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

    for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
        Tab tab = this.newTab();
        this.addTab(tab.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
        AppCompatTextView view = (AppCompatTextView) ((ViewGroup)slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(1);
        view.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is for textview but how can i apply this font style to TABS NAME.

Comment: TextView customTabView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null); tab.setCustomView(customTabView);

Comment: but my TabLayout doesnt have any option like .. tab.setCustomView(customTabView);

Comment: I have made this custom class but not able to apply to my current TabLayout. Sorry for asking so many questions but i am new to android so this i little difficult for me to understand. Can you show me how can i do this.